# Make a particular component visible in a Scrollable JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a scrollable JPanel in which are added many Editor Panes (having their respective Scroll Pane) in Box layout (Vertical Axis).
My problem is that on clicking a particular button I want a particular Editor Pane to gain focus and also be visible on the screen.

I am unable to make that Editor pane visible.

I tried

```
scrollRectToVisible(jScrollPane5.getVisibleRect()); //It did nothing !
```

I also tried

```
scroller.setViewportView(jScrollPane5); // It made the particular editor pane occupy the entire panel !
```

Kindly suggest what to do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invoke `scrollRectToVisible()` on the "Editor Pane" that you want to be visible in the scroll pane.

Also, after clicking on the button it will have focus so you need to use requestFocusInWindow() on the edtitor pane that you want to have focus.

You can also check out [Scrolling a Form](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/scrolling-a-form/) which will do this for you whenever any component in the scroll pane gets focus.

Answer (score 1):

`scrollRectToVisible(theWantedEditorPane.getBounds())`